# Recursive URL routing in Django

Tags: django, url-routing

I want to have a (fairly simple) emulation of `SELECT` queries through URLs.

For example, in a blogging engine, You'd like `/tag/sometag/` to refer to the posts having the `sometag` tag. Also `/tag/sometag/or/tag/other/and/year/2013` should be a valid URL, beside other more complex urls. So, having (theoretically) no limit on the size of the url, I would suggest this should be done recursively, but how could it be handled in Django URL Routing model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a common URL pattern for all those URLs.

```
url(r'^query/([\w/]*)/$', 'app.views.view_with_query'),
```

You would receive all the "tag/sometag/or/tag/other/and/year/2013" as a param for the view.

Then, you can parse the param and extract the info (tag, value, tag, value, year, value) to make the query.

Comment: That would totally ignore the idea behind using URLConf, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but in this case, it is not known the structure of the urls.

Answer (score 1):

#### update 2021

`django.conf.urls.url` is deprecated in version 3.1 and above. Here is the solution for recursive url routing in django:

> urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path, re_path
from .views import index


urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^query/([\w/]*)/$', index, name='index'),
]
```

> views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse


# Create your views here.
def index(request, *args, **kwargs):
    print('-----')
    print(args)
    print(kwargs)
    return HttpResponse('<h1>hello world</h1>')
```

If I call `python manage.py run server`, and go to 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/query/nice/', I can see these in terminal:

```py
-----
('nice',)
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but for those who reach here in future, starting from django `2.0+`, you can use [path converter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#path-converters) with `path` to match the path in the url:

```py
# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('query/<path:p>/', views.query, name='query'),
]
```

```py
# views.py
def query(request, p):
    # here, p = "tag/sometag/or/tag/other/and/year/2013"
    ...
```